# prevent inline-block element moving out of his parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

Jsfiddle showing the issue: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/codendcode/uvxca5mo/22/)

I have a few divs and inside they hold other divs (both created from js),
and an Event handler that shows text ('innerText') when clicked,
my problem is, the event handler makes the whole inner div to drop down, what is causing it?

HTML

```
  <div class="container">
      <div id="board"></div>
  </div>
```

scc

```
.square{

  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 2.3%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center
}
.row{
  height: 50px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

js

```
/* creating state */
var cellsArr = [];
var cell = {state: 'clean', dangerScale:0}
for(i=0;i<100 ; i++){
  var cell = {state: 'clean', dangerScale:0};
  cellsArr.push(cell)
}
var ranArr = [], bomNum = 20;
for(i=0; i<bomNum; i++){
  ran = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
  ranArr.push(ran)
}
for(i=0; i<ranArr.length; i++){
  cellsArr[ranArr[i]].state = 'dirty'
}

/* creating the dom */
var id = 0
for (var i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
  var divRow = document.createElement('div')
  divRow.classList.add('row')

  for (var j = 0; j <= 9; j++) {
    var div = document.createElement('div')
    div.classList.add('square')
    div.id = id
    div.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    div.addEventListener('click',show)
    id ++
    divRow.appendChild(div)
  }
  document.getElementById("board").appendChild(divRow)
}
function show(ev){
  ev.target.innerText = cellsArr[ev.target.id].state;

}
```

Comment: add `vertical-align:top`

Comment: Add `display: flex` to `.row` element

Comment: @Morpheus no need flexbox in this case .. it's a simple alignment issue

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif  that solved the issue